# Is there diffraction in a converging beam of light?

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction

I was thinking that there wouldn't be any diffraction from a converging beam of light since all the light is propagating to a point.

Comment: What do you mean by "a converging beam of light"?  What kind of physical situation are you thinking of that would produce such a beam?

Comment: @michaelseifert Is there any other thing with a beam of light that's converging to a single point?? For example a convex lens scenario. I don't understand how you are confused.

Comment: Your question title asks about convergence in general, but then you ask about convergence *to a single point* in the question text, hence my confusion.  See my answer below.

Comment: Do you really mean *point* or do you mean *small volume*?   If you really mean *point*, watch out.  This is a physically impossible situation.  Light cannot converge to a point.  It's meaningless to ask questions about impossible situations.  You might rephrase this and say "light cannot converge to a point because diffraction is unavoidable"  or something like that.

Comment: @michaelseifert would there be a difference between point and small volume?

Comment: What if the light is converging to a point at infinity (ie parallel)? Do you expect any diffraction then?

Answer (score 2):

Freely propagating light *always* diffracts, whenever its wave nature is detectable.  Even when light is converging toward a point, it never can reach an infinitesimally small point *because of diffraction*. Let the light proceed beyond a "point" focus, and at a large enough distance it will form an Airy disk, a Gaussian pattern, or  other such pattern - again, due to diffraction.

Comment: I mean, are we going to see a diffraction pattern as a converging beam of light goes through an aperture?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your argument.  You say that the light can't reach an infinitesimally small point;  but your counterargument relies on the light proceeding past this point, which kind of implies that this point can exist.

Comment: I used the quotation marks around "point" to indicate that it's not really a point.  I probably should have added a couple of sentences: Because the diffraction is evident at a long distance, it's clear that it is present along the whole (free) propagation path whether it's easily visible or not.  Huygens' principle applies wherever the light is propagating.

Answer (score 0):

Diffraction is almost by definition the spreading-out of waves.  If the wave is converging to a point, then by definition there is no diffraction. One way to see this is to note that a time-reversed wave is also wave;  in other words, if we "film" a wave traveling through space, and we run that film backwards, the film is also a valid way for a wave to behave.  In particular, if we film a wave being emitted outwards from a point source, and run that "film" backwards, the film would show us a wave converging into a single point, without any "spreading" of the wave.

That said, it is important to note that wave fronts can be converging without necessarily converging to a single point.  An example of this is the [caustic networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKM8OFJ0YzM) that you see at the bottom of pools of water, caused by waves on the water surface.  The patterns of light & dark are caused by the convergence of light waves onto whole regions of the bottom of the pool, not just onto a single point.

Comment: But won't a converging wave always converge to a point eventually? Also, a better phrasing of my questions I suppose is that, would a converging wave cause a diffraction pattern when going through an aperture?